# charCodeAt giving wrong charCode

Tags: javascript, jquery, keycode

I have this code that checks for right click + pastes in an input, and then passes the char code of each pasted character into a function. However the char code seems incorrect. I have pasted "fds" into an input and it says the charcode of the first character is 102, but the charcode of "f" is 70.

Here is the code:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.strictNumeric = {
    init: function (element) {
        $(element).bind('input propertychange', function () {
            for (var x = 0; x < $(this).val().length; x++) {
                if (qb.Utils.Number().isAcceptableNonNumericCharacter($(this).val().charCodeAt(x))) {
                    return;
                } else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
```

$(this).val() is equal to "fds". The value of the $(this).val().charCodeAt(x) parameter in the first loop is 102 not 70. Why is this?

Comment: Note that the codes for `fds` (lowercase) are 102, 100, and 115. An uppercase`F` would be code 70. A code of 112 suggests that a `p` is present in the element's value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The charcode for `f` is correctly 102, for `F` it's 70.